# xsetwacom unable to find output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tablet, xrandr

Xrandr shows two monitors. I want to use xsetwacom to move all devices to HDMI-0 however the xsetwacom command towards the bottom does not recognize HDMI-0

Outputs:

```
cloz@CLOZ-ELITE:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  74.99*   59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x768      59.87  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
```

So I try to xsetwacom to HDMI-0

```
cloz@CLOZ-ELITE:~$ xsetwacom --set 'HUION Huion Tablet Pad pad' MapToOutput HDMI-0
Unable to find an output 'HDMI-0'.
cloz@CLOZ-ELITE:~$
```

After I get this to work I can make a script to do it on startup but I can't find any resources on how to fix xsetwacom or xrandr to correctly identify HDMI-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. your case could be related to an old bug that comes with the usage of nvidia drivers
2. xsetwacom '-v' option will output more details (prefixed by '...') eg:

   ```
   $ xsetwacom -v --set "Some Device Name" "MapToOutput" "DP-1"
    ... RandR extension not found, too old, or NV-CONTROL extension is also present.
    Unable to find an output 'DP-1'.
   ```
3. In the case above - "RandR ext. not found" - your monitor must be renamed as 'HEAD-n' where n is the monitor number eg:

   ```
   $ xsetwacom -v --set "Some Device Name" "MapToOutput" "HEAD-1"
   ... Setting xinerama head 1
   ... Remapping to output area 1920x1080 @ 1920,0.
   ... Transformation matrix:
   ...  [ 0.500000 0.000000 0.500000 ]
   ...  [ 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 ]
   ...  [ 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 ]
   ```

Note : the suffix 'n' in 'HEAD-n' is not always the same as the ones used by your nvidia driver (sometimes reversed).

I use this workaround for my Intuos2 Tablet and it works like a charm.

Comment: `HEAD-1` worked great, in my case; I had `HDMI-1` previously, but I didn't use the Huion tablet for a while, finding the old script not working anymore... This fixed it.

Comment: @dentex Consider accepting the answer to make it easier for other people to find.

Comment: @Jesse mine was just a comment. Cloz asked the question.